# isc-dhcp-server (dhcpd) gives old next-server in DHCP offer

Tags: dhcp, pxe-boot, isc-dhcp, bootp

I'm running isc-dhcp-server (dhpcd) version 4.4.1 on ubuntu 20.04 with a subnet configured like so, which has been working just fine.

```
# /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
subnet 10.0.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  option routers 10.0.1.1;
  next-server 10.0.1.2;
  filename "pxelinux.0";
  allow bootp;
  allow booting;

  [..]
}
```

I recently tried changing `next-server` to another IP `10.0.2.2` and restarted the DHCP server, however when a PXE client issues a DHCP discover it responds with a DHCP offer that contains the old next-server IP `10.0.1.2`.

Could it be that the bootstrap protocol (bootp) information linked to a lease? No reference to `next-server` in `/var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases` from what I can see at least.

For what it's worth I tried changing in another subnet and that works, but haven't been able to identify any differences in their configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be caused by class declarations being included inside one of the subnet declarations, when they're actually supposed to be globally defined. In turn this messed with the subnets that were defined, including the one in question.